# Theorem 3.37 of Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

In theorem 3.37 of Baby Rudin. The following claim I can’t understand.
$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{c_{n}} \le \beta$  is true $\forall \beta \ge \alpha$ then we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{c_n} \le \alpha$. I think it related with the concept of supremum, but still I can not prove it satisfactory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given inequality holds for all $\beta \geq \alpha$ so just take $\beta = \alpha$.
If however $\beta < \alpha$ then you can show it using basic properties of limits.

Comment: What do you mean by beta < alpha

Comment: The first sentence of your answer is a complete answer. The second sentence doesn't make any sense -

Answer (score 0):

This actually has nothing to do sequences and limits or supremema.  The following it true for any real numbers no matter what the context.

> If $M \le \beta, \forall \beta \ge \alpha$ then $M \le \alpha$

> Pf: If $M \le \beta$ for all $\beta \ge \alpha$, then for every $\beta \ge \alpha$ we *always* have $M \le \alpha \le \beta$.  So..... $M \le \alpha$.

That's all it's saying.  It isn't deep.  It was probably assumed to be obvious.

And if $M = \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup \sqrt[n]{c_n}$ then it is true for $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{c_n}$